# Create a list of dataframes/data.tables which created from function with argument in R?

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I am impressed by the efficiency R-code could be by using functions and loops.
I will provide a simplified example of the question first, and explain my problem (where the code is probably not replicable).

If I have several vectors which are different in contents and length,like:

```
tables_vector_1 <- c(1,2,3)
tables_vector_2 <- c(1:10)
```

And I have a function to create data.tables from the vector, like:

```
create_dt <- function(tables_vector, i){
  DT <- data.table(id = 1:i,  name = c("a","b","c"))
  return(DT)
}
```

I am wondering, if there is a way to write a loop or function, where I can create all (or some of ) data.tables in the vector by running the function created before?
(probably like)

```
for i in 1:length(tables_vector){
   create_dt(tables_vector, i)
}
```

And then combine the results in a list, same as the result if you run:

```
list(create_dt(tables_vector_1,1),create_dt(tables_vector_1,2),create_dt(tables_vector_1,3))
```

I have tried to use `lapply(list(1:3),create_dt,tables_vector = tables_vector_1, i)`, but it falls, since I don't know how to specify the `i` argument correctly in `lapply()`.


Here is the explanation why this problem rise:
In the real situation, I have created a function to import data.table from the database:

```
import_data <- function(tables_vector,i){ 
  end <- Sys.time()
  start <- end - 7200
  con <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL", dbname="db", host = "host", user=db_user, password=db_password)
  query <- sprintf("SELECT %s.timeutc, %s.scal AS %s FROM %s WHERE timeutc BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' AND mode='General';",
                   tables_vector[i],tables_vector[i],tables_vector[i], tables_vector[i],start,end)
  rs <- dbSendQuery(con, query)
  df <- fetch(rs, n = -1)
  dbClearResult(rs)
  dbDisconnect(con)
  return(as.data.table(df))
}
```

And I have tens of vectors which are defined by groups (e.g. vector1 contains channels for purpose 1, vector2 contains channels for purpose 2). 
Since they are created for different analysis purposes, I cannot simply combine them in one vector.

Moreover, some vector contains 7, 8 channels, so it is quite annoying to list them by repeating the function one by one.

Comment: It's very possible your real use case just need `data.table::rbindlist` and use of the `idcol` argument. But it's hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
tables_vector_1 <- c(1,2,3)
tables_vector_2 <- c(1:10)

create_dt <- function(tables_vector, i){
  DT <- data.table(id = 1:i,  name = letters[1:i])
  return(DT)
}

make_list <- function(x){
  lapply(seq_along(x), function(i)create_dt(x, i))  
}

make_list(tables_vector_1)
[[1]]
   id name
1:  1    a

[[2]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b

[[3]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c

make_list(tables_vector_2)
[[1]]
   id name
1:  1    a

[[2]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b

[[3]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c

[[4]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c
4:  4    d

[[5]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c
4:  4    d
5:  5    e

[[6]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c
4:  4    d
5:  5    e
6:  6    f

[[7]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c
4:  4    d
5:  5    e
6:  6    f
7:  7    g

[[8]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c
4:  4    d
5:  5    e
6:  6    f
7:  7    g
8:  8    h

[[9]]
   id name
1:  1    a
2:  2    b
3:  3    c
4:  4    d
5:  5    e
6:  6    f
7:  7    g
8:  8    h
9:  9    i

[[10]]
    id name
 1:  1    a
 2:  2    b
 3:  3    c
 4:  4    d
 5:  5    e
 6:  6    f
 7:  7    g
 8:  8    h
 9:  9    i
10: 10    j
```

Note, I changed the `create_dt()` function so it did not produce a warning, but the mechanics should still work as intended.